# Port Forwarding Service

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh

I have a machine at home that I run as a server (gaming and things that use a lot of CPU and RAM). I also have a much smaller server in the cloud that I have connected to my domain. I am looking for a reliable to way to forward a port from my home machine to the cloud server. I am using SSH port forwarding on Ubuntu 18.04 on both, and it seems to shut itself off randomly. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make this a better process?

Answer (score 1):

Use a VPN instead.

I posit that the issue you are having in someway relates to NAT. Changing to a VPN - for example OpenVPN  (largely) fixes the issue by abstracting away the IP address / NAT issues, and where these do occur, the VPN will automatically reconnect and do so in such a way as to preserve the session.